# How can I use the \input command in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, input

I have to create a set of `groupplot`s with `pgfplots` and want to use one centralized definition of the plot style (width, height, x-axis label, etc.). It seemed to me that this should be easily done by collecting the definitions in a file that I then `input`. The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  width=6.0cm,height=4.0cm, 
  group style={group size=1 by 2},
  xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,xlabel=$x$,
%  \input{style.tex} % does not work
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,ylabel={$y_2$}]
  \addplot table {
   0.1 0.9
   0.9 0.1
  }; 
  \nextgroupplot[ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,ylabel={$y_1$}]
  \addplot table {
   0.1 0.2
   0.9 0.8
  }; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file `style.tex` contains the following:

```
width=6.0cm,height=4.0cm, 
group style={group size=1 by 2},
xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,xlabel=$x$,
```

If I run the above MWE, `pgfplots` works as intended. If I comment out the lines that are reproduced in `style.tex` and comment in the line containing the `\input` command, I get the following error:

```
! Use of \pgfplots@@environment@groupplot doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.17   ]
```

How come? I thought that the `\input` command [is equivalent to typing out the commands in the file being input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

Comment: Common option of group plot put in `\pgfplotsset{...}` which (for local use) should folow `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way is to define a style with `\pgfplotsset{SomeStyleName/.style={<options>}}`. Note that using `group style={...}` directly in the definition of the new style doesn't work (see [Group style key does not work in pgfplotsset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239794/group-style-key-does-not-work-in-pgfplotsset)), which is why I use the more verbose `group/<key>=<value>`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,
    MyPlotStyle/.style={
       width=6.0cm,
       height=4.0cm,
       xmin=0.0,
       xmax=1.0,
       xlabel=$x$,
       group/group size=1 by 2
       }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
MyPlotStyle
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,ylabel={$y_2$}]
  \addplot table {
   0.1 0.9
   0.9 0.1
  }; 
  \nextgroupplot[ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,ylabel={$y_1$}]
  \addplot table {
   0.1 0.2
   0.9 0.8
  }; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution,  however it make sense, when you have more figures with the common options.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about using `pgfplotsset`, but your answer does not address my actual question - why can I not use `\include`?

Comment: @user1362373 Keyval input is _not_ expanded as it is parsed (LaTeX's `\input`  is not expandable anyway). As such, this will _never_ work: the parser doesn't see the content of your file, it sees `\input...` which then ends up in the wrong places (treated I think as a colour).

Answer (score 5):

Try something as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

    \begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{width=6.0cm,height=4.0cm,  %<-- group plot "style": common options
                 group style = {group size=1 by 2},
                 xmin = 0,  xmax = 1,   xlabel=$x$,
                 ymin = 0,  ymax = 1}
\begin{groupplot}
  \nextgroupplot[ylabel={$y_2$}]
  \addplot table {
   0.1 0.9
   0.9 0.1
  };
  \nextgroupplot[ylabel={$y_1$}]
  \addplot table {
   0.1 0.2
   0.9 0.8
  };
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In above code I use only necessary packages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks also, but your answer also does not address my actual question.

Comment: because the package settings is not design so. They can be used only on the way as described in the both answers.