# Endogenous ticks in pgfplots created by data generating process

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks, axis

I have a two dimensional Data set which is created by an outside program (matlab).

I want to plot this using pgfplots.

I am only interested in two data points on the x-axis. These should get ticks. 
The problem is: The position of these data points depends on the specification of my data generating matlab code and is thus endogenous. *How can I automize the the picture drawing?*

Here is my idea so far: When generating the data I also write down the two values in two separate files `b_value.dat` and `c_value.dat` each containing only that value.

The naive approach was to use the following properties

```
\begin{axis}[%
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick={\input{b_value.dat},\input{c_value.dat}},
    xticklabels={$b$,$c$}
]
```

I understand however from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284867/how-can-i-use-the-input-command-in-pgfplots) that `\input` does not work.

It also seems not to work inside `\pgfplotsset`.

Is there any way to automize this?

*Nasty workaround*: I write the entire `\pgfplotsset`-part in matlab and use `input` for that. I don't like that approach as to my understanding matlab should not write dirty latex. I would prefer to only write the values `b` and `c` as data points from the matlab rountine. *Is this possible?*

(I can include an MWE if demanded, but IMHO it is not necessary and only confusing by the amount of files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already had the right idea to put the coordinates into a separate file, but instead of "`\input`ting" it in `xtick` directly, you should plot it as dummy first plot and use `xtick=data`. This option plots the x coordinates of the first given `\addplot` command and thus gives exactly the result you are searching for.

Please note that *full* coordinates have to be given and the corresponding y values influence the axis limits. So best it is to use the same y coordinate as in your "real" data (or set the axis limits explicitly).

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
    % put the two coordinates for which you want to show the `xtick's here
    % (Optimally provide the "full" coordinate, i.e. including the corresponding
    %  y value, so the axis limits aren't influenced by these dummy data like
    %  shown in this example)
    \begin{filecontents*}{xtick.txt}
        x   y
        0.5 0
        1.5 0
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick=data,
    ]
        % use the first plot to draw the ticks only, so make it invisible
        % and "reset" the `cycle list index`
        \addplot [draw=none] table {xtick.txt};
            \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-1}

        % now you add your normal data
        \addplot coordinates {(1,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]